# Connect bench PSU to PCB containing DC power jack

Tags: power-supply, power-connector

Many equipment uses DC power jacks which look something like this:

[image]

Laptops usually appear to contain something like this which is where we connect its power supply. The basic question is, how to connect to something like this via a bench power supply? We would need to have the corresponding complimentary connector to be able to connect to this. But suppose we don't even know what the size is, where do we start from in that case?

Comment: Some have 2.1mm centre pin, others 2.3mm. Seems to be common for DC, so get the polarity correct!

Answer (score 1):

To connect to it from a bench supply, you can cut the cord off an old adapter (which will yield a nice molded jack-cord assembly) or solder wires to a barrel plug (not as good for strain relief) or buy a molded power cable from a distributor.

If you don't know the size and don't have documentation you can measure it and compare with [catalog](https://www.mouser.ca/datasheet/2/670/pj_102a-1778834.pdf) dimensions. [image]. A set of calipers, and gauge pins (ideally) for the internal hole or just measure random cylindrical objects with your calipers, and [see what fits](https://forum.digikey.com/t/measuring-power-supply-barrel-plug-id-2-1mm-vs-2-5mm/401).

The inner pin diameter has to be accepted by the hole in the mating plug, so a 2.0mm diameter pin might mate with a 2.1mm plug. The other similar common size is 2.5mm, which is  fairly close. There are also other sizes.

And as Glen says, get the polarity right the first time or (oftentimes) there will be no chance for a second time with that particular device as it will be destroyed.

Comment: What does "molded power cable" mean?

Comment: The plug strain relief is molded to the wires (typically with soft pliable plastic in a vertical injection molding machine) so the assembly is more robust than a fabricated assembly. Sometimes the molded strain relief fit is just good enough that it resembles the former in appearance and function.

Comment: [Here](https://tensility.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/pdffiles/053-0196R.pdf?X-Amz-Expires=600&X-Amz-Date=20230711T212434Z&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIS2S4WRDQDSWDRZQ%2F20230711%2Fus-west-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=85129982ae3034887a49160c94e95eae41cfd5a716de555025d581dd6908cb31) for example, the PVC (polyvinyl chloride plastic with a lot of plasticizer additives) overmold portion is indicated.

Answer (score 1):

You try different existing DC barrel plugs from existing devices that seem to have correct match for centre pin diameter and barrell length, including any locking mechanism, such as twist lock or lock screw, if applicable.

Or buy a couple of common sizes that fit most devices. Solder wires and connect to lab supply.

Ensure correct voltage and polarity.